# Office 365 Excel - Turn cell matrix into list without blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel, list

I am trying to take a matrix of 2500x2500 cells (95% of the cells are blank) and create a list without any blanks.

Answer (score 0):

First enter your data in **A1** through **CRD2500**.  Then run this short macro:

```
Sub MakeAList()
        Dim r As Range, N As Long, cell As Range

        Set r = Range("A1:CRD2500")
        N = 1
        For Each cell In r
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                Range("CRE" & N).Value = cell.Value
                N = N + 1
            End If
        Next cell
End Sub
```

The list will appear in column **CRE**.

Comment: Unless there are >=84% blanks, this will crash. Yes, I know the OP specified 95%.